# Sequelize exclude returns different value

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So when I query without attribute: exclude... it returns me the correct user, but when I insert that in the query it returns a completly different user. Here is the code that I'm inserting.

```
const user = await Users.findOne(
    {
      attributes: { exclude: ["password", "admin", "createdAt", "updatedAt"] },
    },
    { where: { id: req.user.id } }
  );
  res.json({ user });
```

Any ideas why is this happening?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'r passing the `where` condition to the second paramter, but according to the docs: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/#findone

`Model.findOne` only has one parameter which is the query options.

Move your `where` condition into the object for the first parameter.

```js
const user = await Users.findOne({
  attributes: {
    exclude: ["password", "admin", "createdAt", "updatedAt"],
  },
  where: { id: req.user.id },
});

res.json({ user });
```

Comment: But I can still use the exclude right? Just have to pass it in the first parameter aswell? Thanks

Comment: @Kosta Yes, everything should work the way you described that you wanted it to function. You just passed the query condition in the wrong place so it wasn't filtering the rows properly.